# How to save String Template as a Text file in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am taking data from .csv file and user to create a string template,Now I want to save this template as a text file.I have assigned the whole template into a single variable as

```
Temp=A, t.substitute(values))
```

but I am getting error.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
def Mail_Temp():

    NSTT=input("Enter Case Number Number :")
    ActDate=input("Enter Activity Schedule date and time:")
    ProD=input("Enter Problem Description")

    A=  """
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    Basic Details Required for Logging Complaints
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        END CLIENT --Internate Network
    ```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````` """
    values={'Dev':HostN, 'Add': Add,'Con':Contact,'Mail':Mail_ID,'SN':SN,'Ven':Ven,'NSTT':NSTT,'ActDate':ActDate,'ProD':ProD}

    #values = {'var': 'HOSTNMAE'}

    t = string.Template("""
    DEVICE HOSTNAME    : $Dev
    CONTACT Person Name: $Con
    EMAIL              : $Mail
    NSTT               : $NSTT
    Device SN          : $SN
    Vendor             : $Ven
    ADDRESS            : $Add
    Problem Description: $ProD
    Note               : Engineer must carry laptop ,console cable & data card
    Activity Schedule  : $ActDate
    """)

    print(A, t.substitute(values))


    Temp = (A, t.substitute(values))
    f= open("Text.txt","w+")
    f.write(Temp)
    f.close()


HostN, Add, Ven, SN, Contact, Mail_ID = get_Data()
Mail_Temp()
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Error::

```
File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx\xxxxx\final data read and select.py", line 59, in Mail_Temp
    f.write(Temp)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple
```

How I can import this template to Text file ...

Comment: The issue has been resolved by doing this, I have combined A and t and printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the question is not very clear. But from the code it is clear that your program is asking for some input and then giving output in a special template format. So here, what I think you really need is a way to **"export"** the template in text format. And not import, like the question says. To export the template you can simply write it out in a text file, and then reuse it however you like, wherever you like.

To export/write in a text file all you need is this example from Quora.

```
def out_fun():
    return "Hello World"
output = out_fun()
file = open("sample.txt","w")
file.write(output)
file.close()
```

Comment: It is interrupting to taking input user creating a loop of input variables .